# How can I concat two columns into one column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am new to Python.I've got two dataframes which are june_df and july_df. The columns are the same, only the values are different.
[Index 62 is the starting point of july_df. How can I concat the column('quantity'), and make it consistent(shown in red cicrles)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAMdf.jpg)

Comment: Useful things when you step into StackOverflow: you can format your variable names (don't overuse though, say up to 4 per paragraph) by enclosing a string in this (`). Also, add links like [this](https://www.google.com), don't make an entire line a link.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend renaming `qunatity` column in one dataframe to `quantity` column. If you do it before concatenation, there will not be any problem after that.

You can rename column using [`pandas.DataFrame.rename()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method like this:

```
my_df = my_df.rename({'qunatity': 'quantity'}, axis=1)
```